# Why is it not suitable for ask how to name a process?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

Here's my question:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/128080/naming-an-operation-hibernate-archive-freeze

I have created a process within a system and wanted to establish if there was some precedent or existing nomenclature for it.  I haven't been able to come up with a good idea, and believing that it might not be a very uncommon process, figured I'd see if anyone else had come across it before or had a good idea.

(I believe that naming classes and processes well is important in a medium-to-large scale system, and IS a part of programming, and valid for asking questions about.)

Anyway, Mark Trapp decided it's not a valid question, saying that it doesn't matter, and that I should ask my team.  My problems with this judgement:

- It matters to me
- I am the team
- I believe the question was closed simply because the mod could not think of a suitable answer
- It was closed, then I was immediately directed to the meta site (personally making a decision, then hiding behind the meta site IMO)

I think it was crappy to close the question within an hour.. I think this is the perfect platform to ask such a question?

Comment: Side-question for bonus points, how can Mark Trapp be a moderator without earning it (6.5k / 10k rep)?

Comment: He was elected by the community.

Comment: @KierenJohnstone 10k gets you access to a subset of moderator tools; it doesn't make you a moderator. Moderators are elected by the community and the amount of rep they have is fairly irrelevant beyond meeting the basic requirements for nominations.

Comment: I think it's a fine thing to ask. Programmers helping programmers with programming tasks and all that. Are we a community of doers or an elitist academic alumni?

Comment: That was my point too.  I may be too easily offended, but when someone personally decides that my honest question is not worthy of other's help when I believe it's important, I think it sucks

Comment: @KierenJohnstone No one decided your question is not worthy of other's help, the only decision was that it was outside the scope of the site. Regardless of what you may think of the closing, your attitude after that wasn't really constructive. You clearly have no (or very little) idea of several aspects of the site (such as how meta works), but still you applied a very aggressive tone in most of your comments. Why? You seem to appreciate the site and the community, otherwise you wouldn't have gone through all this trouble, but do you only appreciate it when it works for you?

Comment: Well I can certainly see how I may have come across as aggressive, but really I was just incredibly disappointed and somewhat insulted.  I absolutely believe that the question is useful to me and possibly others (hence I asked it), and for no reason other than to seemingly satisfy some rule designed to reduce the number of questions on a site which has a low volume of questions.  Considering it's interesting, relevant and highly valuable to me, I didn't like the situation.  I would love to know what people think would be a better platform for my question - it's not SO, it's not programmers..?

Answer (score 6):

Your question is not constructive.

As well as the link to the blog post there are the following two lines in the close reason:

> All questions should be practical, answerable, and of some educational value to the greater community. Chatty, open-ended discussion questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Your question is not "of some education value to the greater community". What you name your operations isn't *that* important.

Your question is a chatty, open-ended discussion where there is no "right" answer. There doesn't have to be a single right answer to a question (there are often many ways of doing things after all), but there should be some answers that are "more" correct than others.

Comment: In my question, I proposed 5 or 6 possible answers, some of which were more correct than the others.  I know that naming things well is valuable, and it would do the greater community some good to see a discussion on it.  It may be a niche problem, but it's not that uncommon and could, of course, be useful in the future.

Comment: Furthermore, there *might well* be an acceptable and "right" answer to that.  In terms of storing an object to disk, it's "serialisation".  Would someone asking for the name of that be a bad question?  For a whole component, just because me, you and the mod can't think of an answer, that means there isn't one?

Comment: You are not asking for the name for something that is known (such as serialisation). You are basically asking what should I call my super cool dog that jumps when I clap my hands twice. There is no correct answer to that. @KierenJohnstone

Comment: phwd - it sounds like you too don't know a name for it.  Are you 100% certain that no-one does?  That was kind of the point of question.  Hibernate sounds about right, but there's no antoym.

Comment: `I'm looking to name a process in my framework` vs `I'm looking *for the* name *of* a process in my framework *I cannot remember it*` are two different questions. The question in its current form is asking for suggestions **not** the correct name. @KierenJohnstone