# Why is it not suitable to ask why a question is not suitable to be asked?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Here's my meta question:

[Why is it not suitable for ask how to name a process?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2765/why-is-it-not-suitable-for-ask-how-to-name-a-process)

I'm presuming it's been downvoted because it's not appropriate to ask questions about questions in meta, despite a mod pointing me at it.

I guess I'm doing it again here (there's no meta-meta that I'm aware of), but if someone could fill me in..

Comment: Downvotes on Meta indicate disagreement, they don't necessarily mean that the question is badly written. The downvotes on your other question just mean that other users disagree with what you wrote on meta.

Comment: Well actually, the tooltip says, `"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"`.  Should I launch a new question to update the tooltip for meta sites?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone Read the [meta faq](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/faq), voting differences are documented in there. The "I disagree" with you meaning of the down vote is a subset of the "not useful" part of the tooltip, I don't really think there's a point in changing it.

Comment: Having seen at least a couple of questions about it on the front page just now, it may be worth it.  But I don't know how common this complaint is, I don't frequent the meta sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Votes on Meta have a different meaning to votes on the main site.

As well as the usual meaning (not enough research, unclear or not useful) down-votes on meta mean things like (but not limited to):

- I disagree with your proposal
- I don't think this is a good feature request
- It's not a bug
- I don't think there is a problem to be solved

There's even a section in the [meta FAQ](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences) about it.

It's one of the reasons why there is no independent reputation on meta sites (apart from Meta Stack Overflow, but that because it's *special*).

I can only guess why people have down-voted your first meta question, but it likely to be because they don't think there's a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this.

Comment: Obligatory FAQ link: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @AnnaLear - you know, I'd forgotten that it was in the FAQ